React Router not rendering dynamic route correctly for IndividualCard component
I'm trying to render a set of pages in React using one dynamic Router, but for some reason my data isn't being found. Here's my code:
// App.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import IndividualCard from './Pages/IndividualCard/IndividualCard';

export default function App() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/introduction/:cardName" element={<IndividualCard />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    )
}

// IndividualCard.js
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function IndividualCard() {
    const { cardName } = useParams();

    // Placeholder data for each Tarot card
    const tarotCardData = {
        'the-fool': {
            image: "/tarot-placeholder.jpg",
            title: "The Fool",
            description: "Placeholder description for The Fool tarot card...",
            keywords: "The Fool's Keywords",
            upright: "Upright meanings for The Fool...",
            reversed: "Reversed meanings for The Fool...",
            titleDescription: "The Fool's Description",
            uprightText: "Upright text for The Fool tarot card...",
            titleReversed: 'The Fool Reversed',
            descriptionReversed: "Reversed description for The Fool tarot card...",
            imageReversed: "/tarot-placeholder-reversed.jpg",
        },
        'the-magician': {
            image: "/tarot-placeholder.jpg",
            title: "The Magician",
            description: "Placeholder description for The Magician tarot card...",
            keywords: "The Magician's Keywords",
            upright: "Upright meanings for The Magician...",
            reversed: "Reversed meanings for The Magician...",
            titleDescription: "The Magician's Description",
            uprightText: "Upright text for The Magician tarot card...",
            titleReversed: 'The Magician Reversed',
            descriptionReversed: "Reversed description for The Magician tarot card...",
            imageReversed: "/tarot-placeholder-reversed.jpg",
        },
        // Add more cards as needed
    };

    const cardData = tarotCardData[cardName];

    if (!cardData) {
        return <div>Card data not found</div>;
    }

    const { 
        image,
        description,
        title,
        keywords,
        upright,
        reversed,
        titleDescription,
        uprightText,
        titleReversed,
        descriptionReversed, 
        imageReversed
    } = cardData;

    return (
        <div className='background_image'>
            <TopNavbar />
            <CardDescription 
                title={title}
                keywords={keywords}
                upright={upright}
                reversed={reversed}
                titleDescription={titleDescription}
                description={description}
                image={image}
            />
            <CardUpright // Render CardUpright component
                title={title}
                uprightText={uprightText}
            />
            <CardReversed
                titleReversed={titleReversed}
                descriptionReversed={descriptionReversed}
                imageReversed={imageReversed}
            />
            <div className="success-story-box-container">
                <SuccessStory />
                <SuccessStory />
                <SuccessStory />
            </div>
            <ContactNavbar />
            <div className="success-story-box-container">
                <SuccessStory />
                <SuccessStory />
                <SuccessStory />
            </div>
            <BottomNavbar />
        </div>
    );
}

However, when I navigate to a URL like /introduction/the-fool, the IndividualCard component doesn't render with the expected data. Instead, it shows "Card data not found". I've ensured that the cardName parameter is correctly extracted from the URL, but it seems like the data lookup is failing.
Any insights into why the dynamic routing isn't working as expected and how I can resolve this issue? Thank you!
I'm implementing dynamic routing in my React app with React Router for tarot card pages. I expected the IndividualCard component to render dynamically based on the URL parameter cardName. However, the data lookup failed, resulting in "Card data not found" instead of the expected content. Any insights on resolving this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!
